# Single listbox component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am confused by which component I should use to allow user to select one item from a list of visible choices, here is what I think come closest to what I need:

[image]

All it need to do is show all the options that's available, with scroll if necessary.

Comment: what is wrong with that component? have you tried it? what seems to be causing confusion?

Comment: It's not a component, the select component is on the right, what I have selected is the example UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lightning-select`, `lightning-combobox`, `lightning-radio-group` and `lightning-checkbox-group` are your most likely candidates.

Comment: "Size" was not in the lighning-select documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:select/specification

Comment: @BillSoftwareEngineer Ah, my mistake. I presumed there was. Still. Either combo box or the radio/checkbox groups should suit your needs.